# Does String.Replace() create a new string if there's nothing to replace?

Tags: c#, string, immutability

For example:

```
public string ReplaceXYZ(string text)
{
    string replacedText = text;

    replacedText = replacedText.Replace("X", String.Empty);
    replacedText = replacedText.Replace("Y", String.Empty);
    replacedText = replacedText.Replace("Z", String.Empty);

    return replacedText;
}
```

If I were to call "ReplaceXYZ" even for strings that do not contain "X", "Y", or "Z", would 3 new strings be created each time?

I spotted code similar to this in one of our projects.  It's called repeatedly as it loops through a large collection of strings.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It does not return a new instance if there is nothing to replace:

```
string text1 = "hello world", text2 = text1.Replace("foo", "bar");
bool referenceEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(text1, text2);
```

After that code executes, `referenceEqual` is set to `true`.

Even better, this behavior is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If oldValue is not found in the current instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged.

Otherwise, this would be implementation-dependent and could change in the future.

Note that there is a similar, [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) optimization for calling `Substring(0)` on a `string` value:

> If startIndex is equal to zero, the method returns the original string unchanged