# How can words entered in the textbox be automatically deleted when encountered in richtextbox? in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to do a filtering algorithm with C#, it will be a textbox and I will enter the forbidden words there. If banned words are found in the text I enter in richtextbox later, the word will be deleted as soon as it is written. How can I do this?

```
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string[] badWords = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        string[] myText = richTextBox1.Text.Split(',');
       

        foreach (var badWord in badWords)
        {
            if (myText.Contains(badWord))
            {

                richTextBox1.Text.Replace(badWord, "");
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Also consider what happens if someone pastes into the textbox.

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# strings are immutable, you need to assign the `Text` property of your `RichTextBox`:

```
if (myText.Contains(badWord))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(badWord, "");
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the `Contains` check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052695/does-string-replace-create-a-new-string-if-theres-nothing-to-replace